# How to switch names between columns in Delta Table - Databricks?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

how to switch in the most effective way names between 2 columns in Delta Lake? Let's assume that I have the following columns:

```
Address |   Name
```

And I'd like to swap names, to have:

```
Name    |   Address
```

First I was renaming two columns:

```
spark.read.table(„table”) \
  .withColumnRenamed("address", "name1") \
  .withColumnRenamed("name", "address1") \
  .write \
  .format("delta") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
  .saveAsTable("table”")
```

Then I rename already renamed columns into the final one:

```
spark.read.table("table”") \
  .withColumnRenamed("name1", "name") \
  .withColumnRenamed("address1", "address") \
  .write \
  .format("delta") \
  .mode("overwrite") \
  .option("overwriteSchema", "true") \
  .saveAsTable("table”")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about just using [toDF function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.toDF) on DataFrame that just sets the new names instead of existing:

```py
spark.read.table("table”") \
  .toDF("name", "address")
  .write....
```

If you have more columns, then you can change it a bit by using mapping between existing & new name, and generate the correct list of columns:

```py
mapping = {"address":"name", "name":"address"}
df = spark.read.table("table”")
new_cols = [mapping.get(cl, cl) for cl in df.columns]
df.toDF(*new_cols).write....
```

Comment: Thanks for that! As I understand this way I need to move data from Delta Table to Data Frame. And what if I'm trying to avoid it? And keep all the time everything in Delta Table? Is there a more elegant way than I did?

Comment: You need to overwrite data anyway. My approach is just more generic